# Is there a way to isolate a button from other buttons on the page with the same name

Tags: jquery

I have jquery code that dynamically generates any number of tr tags that each contain a button with the same name.  When I click on the button it fires all buttons on the page. How can I prevent this.  Since the html is dynamically generated I am not sure how I would independently identify each button element and then retrieve them after it has been rendered. Here is the code:

```
// create order row
var addOrderRow = function(id, name) {
var self = this;
self.Name = name;
self.Id = id;


self.Output = "<tr><th>Code</th><th>Product</th><th>Options</th><th>Size</th><th>Package</th>" +
    "<th>Price</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Delivery Date</th><th></th></tr>" +
    "<tr><td><select name='prodCode'></select></td><td><select name='product'></select>" +
    "</td><td><select name='options'></select></td><td><select name='size'></select></td><td>" +
    "<select name='package'></select></td><td><select name='price'></select></td>" +
    "<td><input type='text' name='quantity'></input></td><td><input type='text' " +
    "name='deliverDate'></input>" +
    "</td><td><button name='addToCart'>Add To Cart</button></td></tr>";

// populate product code
getPcodeProducts();

return self.Output;
};
```

This is the jquery code:

```
var AddToCart = function() {
$("button[name=addToCart]").click(function() {

    $(this).alert('hello');

});
};
```

Comment: Where is your js code?

Comment: .. the id field of the html tag is for this purpose .. so same class of button for styling different id for functionality

Comment: We can suggest a better solution if you tell us what you want to do.  The obvious way to distinguish between your buttons is by using their id attributes.  Since we don't know what you want to happen when you click, it's hard to give more specific advice... But one approach would be to implement buttons that only act on the nearest table row.

Comment: Where's the jQuery code portion of the question?

Comment: You don't need to "identify each button" as such. Attach a click handler that operates on all relevant buttons, then each button will be `this` inside the handler when it fires. Work relative to `this` to select the other elements in the particular table row as required. Pleeeeease, don't be drawn into setting ids.

Comment: I added the jquery. How do I get the alert to fire just once instead of firing for every button element with the same name on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `id` attribute. Downside is you need to keep track of the ids you use to honor uniqueness.

Another option is `$(this)` together with a `data` attribute. This value will not need to be unique.

With jquery you can use `$(this)` in an event handler to get a handle on the element.

```
<button data-id="@id">Add To Cart</button>

$("button[name='addToCart']").on("click", function() {
    var rowId = $(this).data("id");
    alert($(this));  // only one alert occurs
});
```

Working example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jasenhk/HuR6C/)

Comment: Ok, so how would I attach an alert to this, and ensure that it fires only once.

Comment: Only the button instance clicked fires. All buttons matching the selector *can* perform the event handler.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself clearly.  I don't want the other matching selectors to perform the event handler just the actual clicked selector if this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding the buttons through a function there are 2 ways to can add a unique id.

1. If you are willing to use jQuery UI then there is a uniqueId() function that will assign your button a unique id.
   http://api.jqueryui.com/uniqueId/

Ex. `$(curButton).uniqueId()`

1. Create a new unique id on your own.

Ex.

```
var uniId = 0;
$(curButton).attr('id', "u-id-" + uniId++);
```